# How to use custom store methods in svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I'm making a modal, with its attributes stored in a store. Rather than open it like this, from an element: `on:click={() => $modal.isOpen = true}`

I want to open it like this:
`on:click={() => $modal.toggle()}` from an element.

Here is my code:

```
export const modal = writable({
    isOpen: false,
    title: 'Title',
    content: 'Content',
    toggle: () => {
        console.log(modal)
        modal.set({ ...modal, isOpen: true });
    }
});
```

When I log `modal`, it logs just the `set, subscribe, update` methods. Then when I click again, those methods are gone: it properly overwrites them, it just seems that I can never get the modal's initialized state. I've tried to access the current object with `this` or parameters (`(a, b) =>`) but neither return anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The argument passed to `writable` only contains data, not methods. To create a custom store, do it like [this tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores) — create your own store factory that wraps `writable`:

```js
const toggleable = initial => {
  const store = writable(initial);

  return {
    ...store,
    toggle: () => store.update(n => !n)
  };
};

const modal = toggleable(false);
```

Demo here: https://svelte.dev/repl/682ef8309f924ba7ad8de1e2f5069988?version=3.12.1

Comment: Thanks, Rich! I feel like I'm close but I just cannot seem to import this update method properly. Shown here: https://svelte.dev/repl/a5457b36d46d48d4bb271852cf6d0c75?version=3 I've tried all manner of things between the two examples shown (and more) but it seems if I ever get update() working, then something else breaks.

Comment: `store.update` takes a *function*, not a value. The function receives the old value and returns a new one. So it should be `store.update(old => ({ ...old, isOpen: !old.isOpen }))`